# Can i make watch ads button in my application?

Tags: android, google-play, admob

I am making a train android application that user can use while sitting in the train...

I am thinking of adding a button(watch ads) that opens a new Activity that display ads and he can switch between them by a button click...
My question is: is that against the admob privacy policy... or I can do it

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no you **can not** do it , from the official documentation

> Repeated or recurring interstitials
>   Don't overwhelm users with interstitial ads. Repeated interstitial ads often lead to poor user experiences and accidental clicks.
>
> Examples of non-compliant implementations include but are not limited
>   to:
>
> Placing an interstitial ad after every user action, including but not
>   limited to clicks, swipes, etc. ***You should place no more than one
>   interstitial ad after every two user actions within your app***. Please
>   note that this requirement also applies when a user clicks the Back
>   button within the app. Placing an interstitial ad immediately after
>   another interstitial ad was shown to and closed by the user.

for more information please visit this [link](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362)

Comment: but there are some applications that makes it and allow users to gain coins for example on viewing the ads... others do it if u lose and want to continue you view ad so it allow you to continue... and more over I am not tricking them the button is called watch ads so the user can click on it if he wants to watch.

Comment: Yes i know , but your question was about admob policy and for them it's against their policies:)

Comment: how I can do it like others. I do not want them to stop my account and stop the ads so it will be empty Activity... you think I should other than admob... thank you

Comment: i think you can still use admob since you can separate ads with more than two users actions !

Comment: please visit the link i provided you , their give examples for use , an please consider my answer if you found it helpful and correct , thanks

Comment: I read it but I am confused how other developers are using it if it is against the privacy policy of admob... anyway thank you man